# Parsing Nested Json Data in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse some data as follows:

```
subject_data
{"72744387":{"retired":null,"Filename":"2021-07-18  23-16-26 frontlow.jpg"}}
{"72744485":{"retired":null,"Filename":"2021-07-21  07-39-57 frontlow.jpg"}}
{"72744339":{"retired":null,"Filename":"2021-07-17  04-55-03 frontlow.jpg"}}
```

I'd like to get the file name from all of this data, but I'd like to do so without using that first number, as these numbers are randomized and there are a lot. So far I have:

```
classifications['subject_data_json'] = [json.loads(q) for q in classifications.subject_data]
data = classifications['subject_data_json']
print(data[3])
```

This prints `{'72744471': {'retired': None, 'Filename': '2021-07-21  04-11-45 frontlow.jpg'}}`

But I'd like to print just the Filename for each of the data sets. `print(data[3]['Filename'])` fails, and I'm not sure how to get the information without using the number.

Comment: What does `type(data[3])` give you? And what error does `data[3]['Filename']` throw?

Comment: You need to loop over the dictionary for each key.... something like `for dict in data.values(): print(dict['Filename'])`

Comment: I wouldn't call a variable `dict` as `dict()` is an inbuilt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a nested expression

```
print([v['Filename'] for i in data for k, v in i.items()])
```